# Magento 2.4 can't access admin url after fresh installation

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento2.4

I have installed Magento 2.4 on the Wamp server. After a lot of work, I was able to load the home page with the default theme. Now the problem is I can't access the admin URL. It is showing a 404 error. Also, all the links on the home page when accessed show a 404 error. When I remove index.php from the URL I can access the page `http://localhost/timber-traditions/pub/index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC90aW1iZXItdHJhZGl0aW9ucy9wdWIvaW5kZXgucGhwLw%2C%2C/`. But admin URL is not accessible.

Answer (score -1):

Your url format shall be

```
http://your_site_url/admin
```

In your case url might be

```
http://localhost/timber-traditions/admin
```